# Why using the latest url_launcher 6.1.2 not work with pdfs but previous version does?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use url_launcher 6.1.2 https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher/changelog to open  pdf links as well as websites from my webview

This is the link I'm trying
https://www.bseindia.com/xml-data/corpfiling/AttachHis/50710d0d-10c7-407b-84c3-86a0b8aae229.pdf

When I use `launchUrl(Uri.parse(url));`
or `launchUrlString(url)`

I get a blank white screen with this and

Error log shows

```
E/FrameEvents(32530): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
```

However, if I use version 6.0.20

```
launch(url);
```

It works then,

but I don't want to use this as it's depreciated now,

I've added in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`launch()` is Deprecated you have to use `launchUrl()`.

```
launchUrl(
       Uri.parse("https://www.bseindia.com/xml-data/corpfiling/AttachHis/50710d0d-10c7-407b-84c3-86a0b8aae229.pdf"),
       mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
)
```

Try this, works completely fine for me.

you also have to add following in manifest.

```
<queries>
  <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your app makes calls -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your sends SMS messages -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <data android:scheme="smsto" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your app sends emails -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
  </intent>
</queries>
```

link for documentation: https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher